# Getting the selected value of jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a form and it can have multiple jQuery autocompletes. When the form is submitted I want to get the selected values in the autocompletes, dump the values into a hidden text field and submit to the server.

I can't seem to find any info on how to do this.  My code is below which works fine and binds to all textfields with the class autocomplete. Any ideas on this?

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("SearchEmployees", "ProjectBase")",
                    minLength: 3,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Fullname,
                                value: item.EmployeeId
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error: " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                alert("change: " + (ui.item ? ui.item.label : "<no item>"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `submit` event, `.each()` to iterate `.autocomplete` elements, `FormData` `.append()` to append `.autocomplete("instance").selectedItem` `.label`, `.value` to `FormData` object; `$.post()` `FormData` object to server. See [`instance()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-instance)

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData();
  $(".autocomplete").each(function(index, selected) {
    var curr = $(this).autocomplete("instance").selectedItem;
    data.append(curr.label, curr.value);
  });
  $.post("/path/to/server", data);
})
```

Comment: thanks for that guest271314 but that only gets the fullname.  I need the value which should be the employeeid. apologies if that wasnt clear

Comment: _"I need the value which should be the employeeid."_ You set the `.value` of `<input>` to `ui.item.label` at `select` event handler `$(this).val(ui.item.label);`. Set the `<input>` `.value` to `ui.item.value`

Comment: Apologies you are right but thats to prevent the default behavior of autocomplete displaying the id of the employee.  In all honesty i tried something similar to your solution earlier and it didnt work but thought maybe id missed something.  I have no idea how the autocomplete stores (if it does store) the selected employeeid.  My feeling is i will need to add the employee id to a hidden field or similar on the select event of the autocomplete widget

Comment: You can create an array, at each `select` event, push, reset `ui.item.value` of each `.autocomplete` element at array index corresponding to `.autocomplete` element index; at `submit` event set `FormData` keys, values to array values. You could alternatively use `$(this).autocomplete( "instance" )` to retrieve `.selectedItem.value`